# _vm.paginated is not a function error with vue-paginate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

so I have tried using the [Vue-Paginate](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate) plugin, however, I'm seeing the following error.

`_vm.paginated is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <section :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'">
    <!-- Start Results -->
    <h1 class="font-thin text-black text-center w-full">Cruise Results</h1>

    <section class="flex flex-wrap">
      <paginate name="cruises" :list="cruises" :per="3">
        <section class="shadow p-4 mb-4 w-full" v-for="cruise in paginated('cruises')" :key="cruise.id">
          <span class="text-md font-bold">{{ cruise.title }}</span>
          <span class="text-sm font-semibold">{{ cruise.summary }}</span>

          <section class="flex">
            <section class="text-lg">
              <span class="text-black">Inside</span>
              <br>
              <span class="text-red">£{{ cruise.inside }}</span>
            </section>
            <span class="pr-8"></span>
            <section class="text-lg">
              <span class="text-black">Balcony</span>
              <br>
              <span class="text-red">£{{ cruise.balcony }}</span>
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
      </paginate>
    </section>
    <paginate-links for="cruises" :show-step-links="true"></paginate-links>
  </section>
  <!-- Cruise Results -->
</template>

<script>
import firebase from '@/middleware/firebase'
import VuePaginate from 'vue-paginate'

const database = firebase.database()

export default {
  components: {
    VuePaginate
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      cruises: [],
      paginate: ['cruises']
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    database.ref('cruises').on('child_added', snapshot => this.cruises.push(snapshot.val()))
  }
}
</script>
```

I have implemented both firebase and I believe I have followed the documentation correctly.

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add use, like described in 
[setup](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate#setup)

```
Vue.use(VuePaginate)
```

It will add mixins e.g. paginated method.

https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate/blob/master/src/index.js#L16

Comment: I'm using Nuxt so not sure where I can use `Vue.use(VuePaginate)` that's why I registered it as a component.

Comment: @B.J.B  component wont call install function that add mixin. In nuxt you can put it into /plugin/whatever.js and in nuxt.config  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/whatever.js', ]

Comment: So just have the plugin `.js` file just  calling `Vue.use(...)`?